# How can I access a "private virtual" property starting with Underscore through Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I was trying to access the following property using Reflection because I don't have the original source code (suppose this was decompiled through Reflector). It seems that something is special about it being "private virtual" or maybe because it has "_" in the beginning of the property. I can access all the other private properties no problem except this one. Just can't figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
 private virtual String _MyProperty
    {
      get
      {
        return this.__MyProperty;
      }
      [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] set
      {
        this.__MyProperty = "blah";
      }
    }
```

I tried to access it using Reflection as following:

```
ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValue(<class of above property>, "_MyProperty")
```

Using the following method in my ReflectionHelper class:

```
Public Shared Function GetPropertyValue(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal prop As String) As Object
        Dim objectType As Type = obj.GetType()
        Dim bindingFlags As BindingFlags = bindingFlags.GetProperty Or bindingFlags.Public Or bindingFlags.NonPublic Or bindingFlags.Instance

        Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo = objectType.GetProperty(prop, bindingFlags)
        If propInfo Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Property: '" & prop & "' not found in: " & objectType.ToString)
        End If
        Return propInfo.GetValue(obj, Nothing)
    End Function
```

Comment: Does `private virtual` make any sense at all? `virtual` is for future overriding, but `private` is not accessible in derived children.

Comment: `private virtual` doesn't compile for me; as Anthony points out, what would that even mean?

Comment: It's possible your decompilation is simply incorrect. Which tool are you using? Are you 100% sure the property is declared and named the way you think it is?

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually, you can override properties and have virtual and abstract properties, they just can't be private.

Comment: okay, but what is the error? the property is just not found? you can list all the properties yourself by using [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx).

Comment: Maybe the reflector is showing the wrong thing. I am using dotPeek

Comment: @James Michael Hare - The mention of abstract and virtual variables makes total sense.  Of course the MSDN website confuses me because within their example codes they declare only a virtual/abstract methods

Comment: Yup, The property is just not found - PropertyInfo is Nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Going By Vlad's question below the original post I changed the ReflectionHelper function "LookThroughAllBaseProperties" as following:

```
Public Shared Function GetPropertyValue(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal prop As String, Optional ByVal bindFlags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.GetProperty Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance) As Object
        Dim objectType As Type = obj.GetType()

        Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo = objectType.GetProperty(prop, bindFlags)
        If propInfo Is Nothing Then
            propInfo = LookThroughtAllBaseProperties(objectType, prop, bindFlags)
        End If

        If propInfo Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Property: '" & prop & "' not found in: " & objectType.ToString)
        End If
        Return propInfo.GetValue(obj, Nothing)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function LookThroughtAllBaseProperties(ByVal objectType As Type, ByVal name As String, ByVal bindFlags As BindingFlags) As PropertyInfo
        Dim objType As Type = objectType
        While objType IsNot Nothing
            For Each availProp As PropertyInfo In objType.GetProperties(bindFlags)
                If availProp.Name = name Then
                    Return availProp
                End If
            Next
            objType = objType.BaseType
        End While
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

It now finds the property. Maybe now someone can explain why this works...

Answer (score 5):

`private virtual String _MyProperty` should be a compiler error.  I get both "A private method cannot be polymorphic" and "A virtual method cannot be private" when I try this in VS 2010.

This makes sense, because `private` means "cannot be accessed outside of this class (including by derived classes)", and `virtual` means "can be overridden by derived classes".  If you could override the method in a derived class, then you could call it from the derived class, making it no longer private.

I wonder if you were decompling some code that was written in managed C++. I think the following is possible in Visual C++:

```
interface class I
{
  property bool IsOk
  {
    bool get();
  }
};

public ref class A abstract : I
{
private:
  virtual property bool IsFine
  {
    bool get() sealed = I::IsOk::get
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

Edit: I found a bug report that mentioned this as a bug in the Visual C++ compiler: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651255/c-cli-property-overriding-and-renaming.